# extrapolation in graph editor in blender 2.8

Tags: animation, graph-editor

I wanted to create a spiral rotating at constant speed. I created my spiral, made two keyframes with linear interpolation and then wanted to add linear extrapolation, but for some reason, when I right click on the channel in graph editor, all the options under extrapolation are greyed out. I am not sure, whether this is just blender 2.8 thing, or I just made some stupid mistake or overlooked something... What could be the cause of this? Or is there some workaround or something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use/change Animation Extrapolation? (Can't find F-Curves / Animation Modifiers in 2.8(1))](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163045/how-do-i-use-change-animation-extrapolation-cant-find-f-curves-animation-mo)

Comment: yes, it does, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

May the graphs are made readonly by accident.
Go into the graph-editor, position your mouse on the left and expand the graphs label. Then hit TAB and watch, whether the tiny lock symbol shows an opened lock.

Comment: it was open all the time, this isn't it

Comment: Is the according object/armature selected and in the correct mode?

Comment: assuming the correct mode is object mode, it is