# How do I use/change Animation Extrapolation? (Can't find F-Curves / Animation Modifiers in 2.8(1))

Tags: animation

I want to loop keyframes in Blenders Curve Editor. But I can't find a way to do this.

If I select the curve / keys I want to loop and right click and select the animated channel and select "extrapolation method" - they are greyed out and I can't change anything.

It seems like it tries to tell me to use "F-Modifiers" - but I can't find them in the interface ("shift-E" doesn't work as I am using industry standard keys).

A short search in the Blender documentation only reveals screenshots of an older interface version and I can't find the "F-Mod" / "Modifiers" Buttons in the 2.8(1) Version. (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/modifiers.html)

Do you know where I have to click or a tutorial that explains it?

Answer (score 1):

The panel is hidden behind this tiny arrow:

[image]

This expands it and you can select the Modifiers tab (Cycles is the one you want)

[image]

The standard shortcut is "n", but I don't know about the industry compatible keymap.

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much. It's so tiny!

Comment: Sure thing! Be sure to mark the question as answered, so others looking for the same thing know where to search :)

Answer (score 1):

Besides the real settings which I was looking for pointed out by "tobkum" I also found another way to change the greyed out setting:

Selecting the layer / keys then clicking on "Channel" in the Curve-Editor Menu and then Selecting "Extrapolation Mode" also let's me set the modes. But you'd still need the menu pointed out by tobkum for further settings.

[image]