# Python - Linear interpolation before keyframe

Tags: python, animation

I'm having trouble to find a way to set the interpolation before a keyframe. For example, this is useful if you want to animation to continue before the first frame and after the last frame to get correct motion blur.

I haven't found a way in the UI either, as setting the interpolation to linear is not acting the way I want.

Is there a way to do this?

Attaced is an example from Nuke where the interpolation is set to linear before the keyframe (which makes the animation continue).
[image]

Comment: Between keyframes is interpolation, before and beyond is extrapolation. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163045/how-do-i-use-change-animation-extrapolation-cant-find-f-curves-animation-mo

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to follow up with the help from @batFINGER:

```
import bpy

o = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]

for fc in o.animation_data.action.fcurves:
    fc.extrapolation = 'LINEAR'
```